# Jquery tab is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have one problem with click function. I have created this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/0v4dncar/6/) from jsfiddle.net.

In this demo you can see there are smile buttons. When you click those buttons then a tab will be opening on that time. If you click the red button from tab area then the tab is not working there are something went wrong.

Anyone can help me here what is the problem and what is the solution?

The tab is normalize like this working [demo](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/KdwOpr)

```
var response = '<div class="icon_b">
            <div class="clickficon"></div>
                <div class="emicon-menu MaterialTabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab active"><a href="#starks-panel1"> TAB1</a></li>
                        <li class="tab"> <a href="#lannisters-panel1"> TAB2</a></li>
                        <li class="tab"> <a href="#targaryens-panel1"> TAB3</a><span></span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="panels">
                        <div id="starks-panel1" class="panel pactive"> a </div> 
                        <div id="lannisters-panel1" class="panel"> b </div>
                        <div id="targaryens-panel1" class="panel"> c </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';

$(document).ready(function () {

    function showProfileTooltip(e, id) {
        //send id & get info from get_profile.php 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/html/',
            data: {
                html: response,
                delay: 0
            },
            method: 'post',
            success: function (returnHtml) { 
                e.find('.user-container').html(returnHtml).promise().done(function () {
                    $('.emoticon').addClass('eactive');
                });
            }
        });

    }
    $('body').on('click', '.emoticon', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).find('.emoticon_click').attr('data-id');
    showProfileTooltip($(this), id);
});
    $(this).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).find('.user-container').html("");
});
var componentHandler = function() {
  'use strict';

  var registeredComponents_ = [];
  var createdComponents_ = [];

  function findRegisteredClass_(name, opt_replace) {
    for (var i = 0; i < registeredComponents_.length; i++) {
      if (registeredComponents_[i].className === name) {
        if (opt_replace !== undefined) {
          registeredComponents_[i] = opt_replace;
        }
        return registeredComponents_[i];
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function upgradeDomInternal(jsClass, cssClass) {
    if (cssClass === undefined) {
      var registeredClass = findRegisteredClass_(jsClass);
      if (registeredClass) {
        cssClass = registeredClass.cssClass;
      }
    }

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + cssClass);
    for (var n = 0; n < elements.length; n++) {
      upgradeElementInternal(elements[n], jsClass);
    }
  }

  function upgradeElementInternal(element, jsClass) {
    if (element.getAttribute('data-upgraded') === null) {
      element.setAttribute('data-upgraded', '');
      var registeredClass = findRegisteredClass_(jsClass);
      if (registeredClass) {
        createdComponents_.push(new registeredClass.classConstructor(element));
      } else {
        createdComponents_.push(new window[jsClass](element));
      }
    }
  }

  function registerInternal(config) {
    var newConfig = {
      'classConstructor': config.constructor,
      'className': config.classAsString,
      'cssClass': config.cssClass
    };

    var found = findRegisteredClass_(config.classAsString, newConfig);

    if (!found) {
      registeredComponents_.push(newConfig);
    }

    upgradeDomInternal(config.classAsString);
  }

  return {
    upgradeDom: upgradeDomInternal,
    upgradeElement: upgradeElementInternal,
    register: registerInternal
  };
}();




function MaterialTabs(element) {
  'use strict';
  this.element_ = element;
  this.init();
}

MaterialTabs.prototype.Constant_ = {
  MEANING_OF_LIFE: '42',
  SPECIAL_WORD: 'HTML5',
  ACTIVE_CLASS: 'pactive'
};
MaterialTabs.prototype.CssClasses_ = {
  SHOW: 'materialShow',
  HIDE: 'materialHidden'
};

MaterialTabs.prototype.initTabs_ = function(e) {
  'use strict';
  this.tabs_   = this.element_.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  this.panels_ = this.element_.querySelectorAll('.panel');
  for (var i=0; i < this.tabs_.length; i++) {
    new MaterialTab(this.tabs_[i], this); 
  }
};

MaterialTabs.prototype.resetTabState_ = function() {
  for (var k=0; k < this.tabs_.length; k++) {
    this.tabs_[k].classList.remove('pactive');
  }  
};

MaterialTabs.prototype.resetPanelState_ = function() {
  for (var j=0; j < this.panels_.length; j++) {
    this.panels_[j].classList.remove('pactive');
  } 
};

function MaterialTab (tab, ctx) {  
  if (tab) {
    var link = tab.querySelector('a');

    link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var href = link.href.split('#')[1];
      var panel = document.querySelector('#' + href);
      ctx.resetTabState_();
      ctx.resetPanelState_();
      tab.classList.add('pactive');
      panel.classList.add('pactive');
    });   

  }
};


MaterialTabs.prototype.init = function() {
  if (this.element_) {
    this.initTabs_();
  }
}


window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  componentHandler.register({
    constructor: MaterialTabs,
    classAsString: 'MaterialTabs',
    cssClass: 'MaterialTabs'
  });
});
});
```

Comment: what is not working here or what went wrong? Not sure what is supposed to happen.

Comment: @LakmalCaldera Please dear check demo and click one smile icon then you see tab area and then click TAB2 to see it is not showing  `<div id="lannisters-panel1" class="panel"> b </div>`

Comment: @LakmalCaldera i added tab example in question please check it for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [updated and working version](http://jsfiddle.net/axe8bzgu/1/).

What we have to do, is to move the target on the same level as the icon is *(almost like tab and content)*. Instead of this:

```
<div class="emoticon">
    <div class="emoticon_click" data-id="1">
        <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/512/emoticons-wink-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
            <div class="user-container" data-upgraded></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

We need this

```
<div class="emoticon">
    <div class="emoticon_click" data-id="1">
        <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/512/emoticons-wink-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
            // not a child
            <!--<div class="user-container" data-upgraded></div>-->
    </div>
    // but sibling
    <div class="user-container" data-upgraded></div>    
</div>
```

And if this is new HTML configuration, we can change the handlers

1. to target click on div **`"emoticon_click"`**
2. change the content of the sibling (not child) div "user-container"

The old code ***to be replaced***

```
$('body').on('click', '.emoticon', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).find('.emoticon_click').attr('data-id');
  showProfileTooltip($(this), id);
});
$(this).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).find('.user-container').html("");
});
```

will now be replaced with this:

```
//$('body').on('click', '.emoticon', function(e) {
$('body').on('click', '.emoticon_click', function(e) {
    // clear all user container at the begining of this click event
    $('body').find('.user-container').html("");

    // find id
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    // find the parent, which also contains sibling
    // user-container
    var parent = $(this).parent()

    // let the target be initiated
    showProfileTooltip($(parent), id);
});

$(this).on( "click", function() {
    //$(this).find('.user-container').html("");
});
```

Check it in [action here](http://jsfiddle.net/axe8bzgu/1/)

NOTE: the really interesting note was in this [Answer by pinturic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32483309/1679310)

Comment: thank you so so much for your answer Dear. I am very happy now. But How to close the div by clicking on any place ?

Comment: Dear Radim the `.user-container` always stay open. How to close it like when clicking other area ?

Comment: Well, you should hook the event on any elements which should trigger that... but NOT on the Icons or tabs. That's the point. Imagine that you have area "head" (icons and tabs) and below "body"... so that below part should have that event click... does it help? Other words... your approach was not so bad. Really not. EXCEPT... that event click cannot be also on the icons and tabs itself...

Comment: how can i do that Dear Radim ?

Comment: Sir, you are smart ;) I am sure you'd make it.. but there is an example http://jsfiddle.net/d0ywsksk/ ... hope it helps ;)

Comment: i really try that think but it is working just when clicked .theBody div. For example i need when clicked body or html. But if i use body or html then i can not click any tab because it is closing on that time.

Comment: I tried to cover that but had to append another answer with more details and example. Hope it helps...

Comment: Sir,  If possible, can I ask you one more question. Please come chat if you agree to help me i am waiting you Helpful people..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89244/discussion-between-innovation-and-radim-kohler).

Answer (score 1):

I have been debugging your code and this is the result:

you are adding the "tab" under ; any time you click within that div this code is intercepting it:

```
$('body').on('click', '.emoticon', function(e) {       
    var id = $(this).find('.emoticon_click').attr('data-id');
    showProfileTooltip($(this), id);
});
```

and thus the "tab" are built again from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to extend [the first and complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32487049/1679310) with a feature:

> close all tabs if clicked outside of the area of tabs or icons

we just have to

- add some event e.g. to body
- and do check if the click was not on ".emoticon" class elements

There is [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpbm8fev/), containing this hook:

```
$('body').on( "click", function(e) {
    // if clicked in the EMOTICON world... 
    var isParentEmotion = $(e.toElement).parents(".emoticon").length > 0 ;
    if(isParentEmotion){
        return; // get out
    }
    // else hide them
    $('body').find('.user-container').html("");
});
```