# passing parameters using state in angular ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I'm building an app using ionic.

Now I want to pass a variable trough a url using state but it does not work. What is the best way to to this?

My approach:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('orders', {
        url: "/orders",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "views/side-menu.html",
        cache: false,
        controller: 'OrderCtrl'
    })

    .state('orders.view-order', {
        url: "/view-order?orderid", //<---- THIS ONE
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "views/view-order.html"
            }
        },
        cache: false
    })

    .state('orders.open-orders', { 
        url: "/open-orders",
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "views/open-orders.html"
            }
        },
        cache: false
    })
```

i have a base controller "dashboard" from where i want to send to order using

```
$state.go("orders.view-order", {'orderid': '232323232'});
```

and then the order controller... (shows only a empty object :(

```
angular.module(appName).controller('OrderCtrl', 
 function($location, $rootScope, $scope, $ionicPopup,
   $state, $stateParams, $auth, $ionicLoading, 
   $timeout, $interval, newOrderService, jwtHelper){

    console.log($stateParams)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`'OrderCtrl'`** belongs to **parent** state

```
.state('orders', {
    controller: 'OrderCtrl'
    ...
```

while the parameter **`orderid`** is defined on a child state:

```
.state('orders.view-order', {
        url: "/view-order?orderid", // here is param defined
```

And that means, that parent cannot access these parameters - because they are defined for its child

So, we can either 
1) move parameter to parent ***(I would say this is the way)***

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMWwQCoF7BwpOBBWV2r3?p=preview)

```
  .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent/:parentId",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'ParentCtrl',
  })
  .state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child/:childId",
      template: 'this is a child view',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
  })
```

or 2) use this trick, when we place the $stateParams into $rootScope and can observe its latest value everywhere:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v1mMJXMQAEpW7UBc2FEq?p=preview) with these example states

```
  .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
  .state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child/:childId",
      template: 'this is a child view',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
  })
```

Comment: i see so i have to attach all the params even if its used for a child to the parent?

Comment: I tried to show you some solution in plunkers which I added. Hope this could give you more ideas how to work with mighty UI-Router...

Comment: @innovation I checked your issue and added working example and some explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32487049/1679310, hope it helps