# Can't retrieve params for a given id in Angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Im building an application in Ionic and I need to display several things from list to details. Basically I have a Homepage that display all my content from a json file, and put it into a list

home.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="item({itemId:item.id})">
          <div class='card'>
            <div class="item item-divider">
              {{item.title}}
            </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
              {{item.text}}
            </div>
            <div class="item item-divider">
              {{item.id}}
            </div>
          </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller to display all items in home.html

```
//factory to get data from data.json

.factory('myFactory', function($http) {
return $http.get('data.json');
})

//Controller home display the whole list

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($ionicModal, $scope, myFactory) {

 myFactory.then(function(response) {
 $scope.items = response.data;
 /*console.log(response)*/
 });
```

And when I click on one element from the list, I want to be redirected to the specific content of the matched id :

item.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Module">
 <ion-content class="has-header">
  <h1>{{$stateParams.itemId}} (doesn't work)</h1>
   <p>
    <!-- content information from given id... -->
   </p>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller for single item

```
.controller('ItemCtrl', function($stateParams) {
 console.log($stateParams.itemId);
 })
```

But I can't even display the selected id from the url in my html ! and can't retrieve any element from that id... I'm so lost right now !
I've seen about state.go with given parameters but thats not what I want to do. I tried assigning different variables but cannot figure it out right.

my json file looks like this :

```
[
 { "title": "Emploi du temps", "text": "text", "id": 1, "content": "text" },
 { "title": "Agenda/bons plans", "text": "text", "id": 2, "content": "text"},
 { "title": "Transport", "text": "text", "id": 3, "content": "text" },
 { "title": "Sécurité", "text": "text", "id": 4, "content": "text" }
]
```

State looks like this :

```
//States

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  })

  .state('item', {
    url: '/home/:itemId',
    templateUrl: 'templates/item.html',
    controller: 'ItemCtrl'
  })
```

I've spent days on this and I've read alot about similar questions but I cannot seem to make it work... Its like Im missing the whole thing. I wish I could do it the way we do in PHP (similar to get *** from *** where id = *)
Please help , thank you :)

Comment: have you defined a state configuration somewhere?
eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484987/passing-parameters-using-state-in-angular-ionic

Comment: oh yes, of course, forgot to add it, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a mistake -

```
Actually $stateParams object can not synchronized with our view.
So don't use this for views.

**Solution-**
```

> We can use $scope and attach a property to it i.e itemId.
>       $scop is able to make interaction with UI(view).

**item.html:**

```
<ion-view view-title="Module">
 <ion-content class="has-header">
  <h1>{{$scope.itemId}}</h1>
   <p>
    <!-- content information from given id... -->
   </p>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controller for single item:**

```
.controller('ItemCtrl', function($stateParams) {
     $scope.itemId = $stateParams.itemId;
 })
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out. But it doesn't solve my main question which is, how can I retrieve other params with that specific id ?
I have access to $scope.itemId but can't access other property of my json object... (i.e. title, text etc...)
Should I re inject my factory in order to have access to the array, and then read data where id = id ? (or with a $filter ?) Im lost :(